# Fullscreen dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have a camera app that runs fullscreen as in no topbar and no android control buttons. On this screen I also show a Dialog with a bunch of options, the problem is as soon as the dialog shows up the topbar and buttons show up as well. I posted a screenshot.

I tried with

```
    alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

But it did not work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround is to give full-screen theme to dialog.

```
<style name="full_screen_dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

and initialize you Dialog like

```
Dialog kek = new Dialog(Product_List_View_All.this,R.style.full_screen_dialog);
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

try this code: it works for me..

```
   mDialog = new Dialog(this,
            android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    mDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    mDialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog_layout);
```

in styles.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a `DialogFragment`? Adding the below line to its `onCreate()` fixed this issue for me.

```
this.getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: With this I get no title, but the back, home buttons are still there :(

Answer (score 0):

try using the below line of code:

```
alertdialog.getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```